# Adding proxy for class hidden behind interface

Tags: magento2, api, dependency-injection, proxy

If I want to add proxy for class `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` (for example it is used only in catch block, which is not reached with every request) in my `di.xml` I should replace it with proxy like this:

```
<type name="some\class\path">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">Psr\Log\LoggerInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

or I have to put class implementing/hidden by some APIs behind this interface - something like:

```
<type name="some\class\path">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">some class implementing\hidden behind Psr\Log\LoggerInterface</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference.
First option should work perfectly fine.

```
<type name="Company\Module\Model\Customer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">Psr\Log\LoggerInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Same way you can also specify a plugin based on Interface.

```
<type name="Company\Module\Plugin\Logger">
   <plugin name="logger" type="object">Psr\Log\LoggerInterfacePlugin />
</type>
```